# Datatables pagination CSS formatting

Tags: css, datatable, pagination

I am using datatables from https://datatables.net/

Codepen - https://codepen.io/raj2619/pen/eYyEjEE

I've used the following CSS to highlight the items clicked in the pagination bar

```
        #example_paginate {
        color:rgba(255, 110, 0, 0.8);
        font-size:19px;
        font-family:"Trebuchet MS";
        }   
        .page-item.active .page-link {
        color: #fff !important;
        background: green;              
        background-color: #000 !important;
        }
        .page-link {
        color: #000 !important;
        background-color: #fff !important;
        border: 1px solid #dee2e6 !important; 
        }
        .page-link:hover {
        color: #fff !important;
        background-color: #000 !important;
        border-color: #000 !important; 
        }
```

However, this doesn't highlight the entire background of the clicked page number. It just highlights the number. What tweaks do I need to highlight thee entire background of the clicked page number?

Currently it looks as below -

[image]

I'm wanting to make it look something like below.

[image]

I'm by no measure a CSS expert. I would appreciate nay help here please.

Comment: I think you should post your HTML as well

Comment: Thank you Jonas. Here's the codepen - https://codepen.io/raj2619/pen/eYyEjEE

Comment: I've updated the codepen with latest code. The only thing pending now is to be able to ahve round buttons (<li> items). Please can someone help with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To gain round buttons you can add this rule to your CSS (you can tweak the padding to get exactly the desired result):

```
.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button {
   border-radius: 50% !important;
   padding: 0.5em 0.9em !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This shows an oval when clicked which vanishes right after the mouse button is released. "after click" state is still the default square.

Comment: Really? I can see the oval on the active button even when releasing the mouse

Comment: Thank you CheesyMan. I'll settle with this.